# How can I monitor syscalls in all processes in Android?

Tags: android, monitoring, system-calls

I want to monitor syscalls in all processes in Android.
I try to use `strace` but it makes devices very slow. `-c`seems not print statistical result in console when I press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.
I also find that `pstrace` can monitor syscalls, however it cannot be used in command line.
So is there any other tool that can help me monitor all syscalls in all processes in Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overhead of `strace` may be too large in android, so other ways to evaluate the performance of android is recommended, for example analyze frame rate.